# Android AppAuth - following the PendingIntent object

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, appauth

I've been trying to implement Google's AppAuth library in Android but I'm struggling to get this working. I've been trying to follow the [guide from Google](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appauth-android-codelab/#7) and apply that to my own codebase but I'm stuck around the pending intents.

More specifically, when I call the `performAuthorizationRequest()` method, the emulator can follow the redirect to obtain the auth code in it's custom tab (I can see it). However, no handler is being called. I've tried adding `onNewIntent()`, `onActivityResult()` and `onResume()` but none of them are being called.

From the Javadocs from `performAuthorizationRequest()`, I see that

> "the provided {@link PendingIntent completion PendingIntent} will be
> invoked".

What does that mean? How can I interact with the completed pendingIntent object? Is there any way that I can retrieve that context using the request code send when the pending intent was being created?

Here's my code below:

```
var authReq: AuthorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
            serverConfig,
            clientId,
            ResponseTypeValues.CODE,
            redirectUri
).build()

val service: AuthorizationService = AuthorizationService(view.context)

val action = "com.google.codelabs.appauth.HANDLE_AUTHORIZATION_RESPONSE"
val authIntent = Intent(action)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, authReq.hashCode(), authIntent, 0)

service.performAuthorizationRequest(authReq, pendingIntent)
```

Inside my manifest, I've added the activities:

```xml
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.codelabs.appauth.HANDLE_AUTHORIZATION_RESPONSE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:scheme="com.google.codelabs.appauth"/>

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after spending a few more days on this, I realized that I messed up the redirect URI and the data elements for the RedirectUriReceiverActivity. Somehow, [this resource](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/authorize-android-appauth-identity-server-3/) helped me understand what I was missing.

Inside the AndroidManifest.xml, the RedirectUriReceiverActivity needs to know where to send the completion back. Also my redirect uri (inside my authReq) was set to an external address, I changed it to using an Android deeplink.